# Downloading a YouTube video through Wget

Tags: youtube, firebug, wget

I am trying to download YouTube videos through [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget). The first thing necessary is to capture the URL of the actual video resource. Suppose I want to download this video: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-KBncrOggI). Opening up the page in the [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) console reveals something like this:

[image]

The link which I have encircled looks like the link to the resource, for there we see only the video: http://www.youtube.com/v/r-KBncrOggI?version=3&autohide=1. However, when I am trying to download this resource with Wget, a 4 KB file of name **r-KBncrOggI@version=3&autohide=1** gets stored in my hard-drive, nothing else. What should I do to get the actual video?

And secondly, is there a way to capture different resources for videos of different resolutions, like 360px, 480px, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not that easy do get the right link for the video resource.

The link you got, http://www.youtube.com/v/r-KBncrOggI?version=3&autohide=1, points to the player rather than the video itself. There is one Perl utility, [youtube-download](https://metacpan.org/module/XAICRON/WWW-YouTube-Download-0.43/bin/youtube-download), which is well-maintained and does the trick. This is how to get the HQ version (magic `fmt=18`) of that video:

```
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~$ youtube-download -o "{title}.{suffix}" --fmt 18 r-KBncrOggI 
--> Working on r-KBncrOggI
Downloading `Sourav Ganguly in Farhan Akhtar's Show - Oye! It's Friday!.mp4`
75161060/75161060 (100.00%)
Download successful!
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~$
```

There might be better command-line *YouTube Downloaders* around. But sorry, one doesn't simply download a video using Firebug and wget any more :(

The only way I know to capture that URL manually is by watching the active downloads of the browser:

[image: Chrome inspector]

That largest data chunks are video data, so you can copy its URL:

http://s.youtube.com/s?lact=111116&uga=m30&volume=4.513679238953965&sd=BBE62AA4AHH1357937949850490&rendering=accelerated&fs=0&decoding=software&nsivbblmax=679542.000&hcbt=105.345&sendtmp=1&fmt=35&w=640&vtmp=1&referrer=None&hl=en_US&nsivbblmin=486355.000&nsivbblmean=603805.166&md=1&plid=AATTCZEEeM825vCx&ns=yt&ptk=youtube_none&csipt=watch7&rt=110.904&tsphab=1&nsiabblmax=129097.000&tspne=0&tpmt=110&nsiabblmin=123113.000&tspfdt=436&hbd=30900552&et=110.146&hbt=30.770&st=70.213&cfps=25&cr=BR&h=480&screenw=1440&nsiabblmean=125949.872&cpn=JlqV9j_oE1jzk7Zc&nsivbblc=343&nsiabblc=343&docid=r-KBncrOggI&len=1302.676&screenh=900&abd=1&pixel_ratio=1&bc=26131333&playerw=854&idpj=0&hcbd=25408143&playerh=510&ldpj=0&fexp=920704,919009,922403,916709,912806,929110,928008,920201,901451,909708,913605,925710,916623,929104,913302,910221,911116,914093,922405,929901&scoville=1&el=detailpage&bd=6676317&nsidf=1&vid=Yfg8gnutZoTD4G5SVKCxpsPvirbqG7pvR&bt=40.333&mos=0&vq=auto

However, for a large video, this will only return a part of the stream unless you figure out the URL query parameter responsible for stream range to be downloaded and adjust it.

A bonus: everything changes periodically as YouTube is constantly evolving. So, don't do that manually unless you carve pain.

Comment: Okay, but how does the Perl script do that? Somehow, one has to get hold of the video resource, right?

Comment: From its list of dependencies, I came across this link: https://metacpan.org/source/WWW::YouTube::Download. Can you understand the logic? I am quite comfortable with Perl, but still I can't understand head or tail of it.

Comment: It is basically a web-scraper. Edited my answer to illustrate the underlying process.

Comment: Yeah, but for the web-scraper to scrape the web-page and find the link, the link has to be there somewhere. Where is it? And if not, then the URL is being constructed? What logic is going into the construction? And yes, YouTube is constantly changing. So will this Perl script work now?

Comment: The link has a signature (BBE62AA4AHH1357937949850490) which is used to construct a cookie used to authenticate the video download session. So that script scrapes the signature somewhere in the `<script>` section, builds that URL and constructs the HTTP request signed with the appropriate cookie. The WWW::YouTube::Download script is well-maintained. It is constantly tested and has an excellent track record: http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/W/WWW-YouTube-Download.html

Comment: By tested I meant for each new structure of Youtube page, not Perl version. Youtube is recently changing its page structure quite furiously.

Comment: Check the [Changelog](https://metacpan.org/source/XAICRON/WWW-YouTube-Download-0.43/Changes); it also seems to be updated furiously :) The CPANTesters structure is capable of detecting when the YouTube design changes and crashes the scraper; not only OS/Perl version compatibility.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty cool then. This whole shebang looks enormously complex, what should be my entry point to start trying to learn it?

Comment: My bad, is seems to not use cookie-based authentication anymore. Check my another answer for a working siplified youtube-download.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one **VERY** simplified, yet functional version of the [youtube-download](https://metacpan.org/module/XAICRON/WWW-YouTube-Download-0.43/bin/youtube-download) utility I cited on my another answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# CPAN modules we depend on
use JSON::XS;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI::Escape;

# Initialize the User Agent
# YouTube servers are weird, so *don't* parse headers!
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(parse_head => 0);

# fetch video page or abort
my $res = $ua->get($ARGV[0]);
die "bad HTTP response" unless $res->is_success;

# scrape video metadata
if ($res->content =~ /\byt\.playerConfig\s*=\s*({.+?});/sx) {

    # parse as JSON or abort
    my $json = eval { decode_json $1 };
    die "bad JSON: $1" if $@;

    # inside the JSON 'args' property, there's an encoded
    # url_encoded_fmt_stream_map property which points
    # to stream URLs and signatures
    while ($json->{args}{url_encoded_fmt_stream_map} =~ /\burl=(http.+?)&sig=([0-9A-F\.]+)/gx) {
        # decode URL and attach signature
        my $url = uri_unescape($1) . "&signature=$2";
        print $url, "\n";
    }
}
```

Usage example (it returns several URLs to streams with different encoding/quality):

```
$ perl youtube.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-KBncrOggI | head -n 1
http://r19---sn-bg07sner.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?fexp=923014%2C916623%2C920704%2C912806%2C922403%2C922405%2C929901%2C913605%2C925710%2C929104%2C929110%2C908493%2C920201%2C913302%2C919009%2C911116%2C926403%2C910221%2C901451&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1357996514&cp=U0hUTVBNUF9FUUNONF9IR1RCOk01RjRyaG4wTHdQ&id=afe2819dcace8202&ratebypass=yes&key=yt1&newshard=yes&expire=1358022107&ip=201.52.68.216&ipbits=8&upn=m-kyX9-4Tgc&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&itag=44&sver=3&source=youtube,quality=large&signature=A1E7E91DD087067ED59101EF2AE421A3503C7FED.87CBE6AE7FB8D9E2B67FEFA9449D0FA769AEA739
```

Comment: Please explain the logic, it's more than Greek to me!